# Assigning a CSS style to a variable value in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I'm quite new to PHP and I've written a login script to go on my website. I can manage to style the text from my stylesheet but the username session variable I'm unable to style, how would I apply a css style to it?

My code is below...

```
<?php
        if (isset($_SESSION["signedin"])){
            echo '<a href="logout.php" class="subheading">Log Out</a>';
            echo " ".$_SESSION["username"];
            }
            else {
                echo '<a href="login.php" class="subheading">Login</a>';
            }
    ?>
```

I have a style called para2 in my stylesheet which I'd like the returned username to be styled in but I can't get it to work without throwing up an error, or the page ignoring the class that's assigned to it and it defaulting to the regular blue text of the browser.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the css that you have written for this too please

Comment: Oh magic crystal ball, reveal unto us this elusive *"error"* OP speaketh of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not put paragraph tags around the username so you can style the text. e.g.

```
  echo '<p class="para2"> '.$_SESSION["username"].'</p>';
```

Comment: Why mix quotes like that? Even OP is using single-quotes

Comment: Ok, now you've just made it worse

Comment: `echo '<p class="para2">'`

Comment: @Phil that works but puts the username on a separate line. how would I be able to keep it on the same line as where it says logout?

Comment: use <SPAN> instead of <P> OR update your para2 style to display:inline;

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your css:

```
a.subheading   {
    color: #333; /* change color accordingly */
}
```

Comment: Do post the css too so I can provide a more specific answer for your problem

Comment: .heading2{
 color:grey;
 font-size:24px;
 text-align:left;
 font-family:"helvetica neue";
 padding-top:4px;
 }

.subheading{
 color: #a685dd;
 font-size:24px;
 font-family:"helvetica neue";
 }

.subheading2{
 color:grey;
 font-size:18px;
 }

.para{
 font-family:"helvetica";
 font-size:20px;
 }

.para2{
 font-family:"helvetica neue";
 font-size:15px;
 color:#606060;
 }

.para3{
 font-family:"georgia";
 font-size:12px;
 color:grey;
 }
 
.headertext{
 font-family:"calibri";
 font-size:18px;
 color:blue;
 }

a.subheading:link {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-style: italic;
 }

Comment: @zxcv5 ... **to your question**

Comment: Add the above to your css and it should work fine. You can add an !important just in case some other css is overriding it like this `color: #333 !important;`

Comment: @AndrewLyndem thanks for your help Andrew, got it sorted out now. I've still a lot to learn! :)